# How do the SG Teams stay alive in wormholes?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

As we know, SG Teams exploring other planets do so with star gates. Star gates are based on wormholes.

How does the team stay alive when going through the wormhole? As I know, wormholes don't have standard oxygen and temperature levels.

Comment: Are the transition times between entering one stargate and exiting another so long that they'd have to hold their breath? I never got that impression from the show (though it has been a while since I watched it).

Comment: I've edited this to try and improve some of the grammar in places, if you feel like I've changed the meaning of your post or you just simply don't like my changes please [edit] your post.

Comment: Logically theory. 

In the first episode, team exited from Stargate as little frozen. 

Thanks @TheLethalCarrot for grammar edit

Comment: "The Stargate creates its own event horizon just in front of the wormhole and dematerializes any object attempting to pass through it so it is not damaged or killed by the deadly low temperatures." https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Wormhole

Comment: The original film seemed to indicate that the time spent in the wormhole is brief, but non-trivial.

Comment: @nicolallias That seems like the answer, do you want to post it as one? Though unfortunately the wiki is unsourced here.

Comment: Exactly why I put that as a comment :) That may be a hint to the actual answer (I also remember the sneezing meme in the movie... May not be related to the stargate itself https://forum.gateworld.net/threads/42740-Will-we-ever-Daniel-sneeze-again

Comment: @KeremBeyazit - Related fun fact: In the episode [Prisoners](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Prisoners) one of the SGC members gives a tip to General Hammond saying, "Since this is your first time, sir, a quick word of advice. It's better to exhale just prior to crossing the event horizon. One's instinct is to inhale immediately upon arriving on the other side..."

Comment: Another related fun fact: the freezing effect you allude to was explained to be a facet of the rematerialisation process (under certain circumstances) - it's not because they've physically spent time in a vacuum.

Answer (score 10):

They dont, they're ripped into their constituent particles per the Stargate wiki: https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate

> "Travel through a Stargate is strictly one-way: from the dialing gate to the receiving gate. This is not a limitation of the wormhole, but of the technology; wormholes will transmit anything that enters them, but no solid matter could survive the process. Thus, each gate in the pair takes on a specific role: the dialing gate converts the traveler into its most basic components (sub-atomic particles) and transmits it, while the receiving gate reassembles the transmitted matter back into its original form. Doing the reverse is not only fatal for the traveler, but would just result in the dialing gate deconstructing the object upon arrival, converting it into energy much like the process of ascension."

So really, they're not actually alive during transmission anyway.

Comment: You mean it's similar to beaming up tech.

Comment: Kerem, per my understanding, yes it is similar to transporter tech in Star Trek

Comment: Beam me up Scott!

Comment: Interestingly, Carter suggests several times (at least one was in _Prodigy_) that the one-way travel restriction comes from wormhole physics, rather than (or, at least, in addition to) from the Stargate technology itself.

Answer (score 5):

The [original script for Stargate (the Movie)](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/episoderedux/movie/stargate_movie_draft_script.doc) indicates that the users of the stargate are torn apart into their constituent atoms, translated through another dimension and then re-constituted at the other end. The swirly-vortex-water-flume effect we while they're traveling see is *from the perspective of the audience*, not the traveler.

> Daniel shuts his eyes and steps into the beam.
>
> Before our eyes we SEE Daniel broken down to the molecular level…
>
> …he enters another dimension.  A fourth dimension…
>
> …traveling over millions of light years outside of our own time continuum…
>
> …we then enter a gigantic black space, floating…until a sun-like light RUSHES towards us, engulfing us…
>
> …the screen BURNS to COMPLETE AND TOTAL WHITE…
>
> Slowly out of the bright white light, a face forms.  Molecules rush together.  It’s Daniel, covered with frost, dropping down to his knees, clutching himself in pain

Comment: I think it was in _Origins: Catherine_ where someone expressed awe at what they'd experienced during transit, remarking on having "seen stars" or somesuch.* But that was clearly nonsense writing which we can choose to decanonicalise :) See also: it was pretty well-established that gate travel used to take actual seconds, until later seasons came up with a new sub-second number and ran with it for the rest of the show. Mind you, that's moot from the POV of the traveler (as I believe we witness "visually" in _Shades of Grey_) since they lack consciousness during that time.

Comment: * Though it's possible I'm thinking of another show, because a couple have done wormholes lately

Comment: Yeah, there it is: _"Did you guys see those? What the bloody hell was that? I think they were stars."_ I suppose it's possible this was some psychological effect upon rematerialisation (like when you get up too fast and "see stars" due to blood rush)

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit - Are you getting it mixed up with "*Wormhole X-Treme!*"? It had very similar themes...

Comment: I just saw this Origins episode and came here looking for the "I think they were stars" because I knew people were dematerialised when entering the gate. I love your explanation that it was a psychological effect! Anyway in the episode "48 hours" Teal'c was trapped in a gate (stored in a memory buffer) for 48 hours and when he got out he haven't noticed anything unusual